# Passing a set of value to a WHERE clause without using IN Operator

Tags: mysql, loops

I have this Query

```
SELECT 
    ID, isDebit, AccountID, SUM(Amount) AS Amount
FROM
    journaltransactions
WHERE
    AccountID IN (45,23,78,90,37,48)
```

Any one have idea to solve the same **without using IN Operator**.

Is it possible to iterate through this set of value in Procedure or something

I have no idea to solve this without **IN Operator**

Any help will be appreciatable

Comment: why are you avoiding `IN`? Are you trying to make it quicker? Where is the accountID list coming from? You can iterate result set in application code, procedures aren't required. Do you mean to have `GROUP BY AccountID` in your query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I do not particularly understand the requirement for not using `in` operator, it can be achieved through a series of `or`:

```
SELECT 
    ID, isDebit, AccountID, SUM(Amount) AS Amount
FROM
    journaltransactions
WHERE
    AccountID = 45 OR
    AccountID = 23 OR
    AccountID = 78 OR
    AccountID = 90 OR
    AccountID = 37 OR
    AccountID = 48
```

Pls note that this query may be slower than the one using `in`.